# Combine rows into one result and add results as different values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (people) that include the following information:

```
  id  cert_id  type    name 
  1     123    owner   Paul
  2     123    seller  George
  3     123    buyer   steve
  4     456    owner   micheal
```

I also have a table (items) that includes the following:

```
id  cert_id  item_name     
1     123    staples
2     123    cheese
3     123    iguanas
4     456    pie
```

Basically, what I want to do is have the results as the following:

```
cert_id  owner_name  seller_name  buyer_name  item_name 
  123    Paul        George       steve       staples, cheese, iquanas
  456    micheal                              pie
```

So far I have been able to use `MAX(CASE WHEN people.type='owner' THEN people.name END) AS owner_name`, but I cannot get the seller name to append to the other row ('im not sure if this is even possible via the SQL statement or if I should do some formatting with the results afterwards. Any advice on combining rows would be helpful, or a simple "not possible" would let me know what the limitations are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could a **single** `cert_id` have **multiple** `owners`, `sellers`, or `buyers` ?

Comment: no. there is only one of each for a cert. The DB is a relic from 2003 and was not setup well. I'm just trying to get the info into a more usable form for migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the following query to get the result:

```
select p.cert_id,
  max(case when p.type = 'owner' then p.name end) owner_name,
  max(case when p.type = 'seller' then p.name end) seller_name,
  max(case when p.type = 'buyer' then p.name end) buyer_name,
  array_agg(distinct i.item_name) Items
from people p
inner join items i
  on p.cert_id = i.cert_id
group by p.cert_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/10d23/12)

Comment: Brilliant! Let me try this out and see if I can get it to work properly.

Comment: @DavidZiemann Happy to help, my suggestion is if you have another issue post a new question. Unfortunately I cannot help with grails.

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished using INNER JOIN or LEFT-OUTER-JOIN...